# Angular 8 : this.http.get is not a function

Tags: angular, rest

I read several question concerning the same issue, without finding answer. 
I try to use a web service to display data in an angular component. 
For this i created a model, a service and a component. I was used to build such request with the old HttpClient.

Here is my model which define the fields.

```
export class CryptoCurrency {
  constructor(private _id: number,
              private _currencyKeyId: string,
              private _currencyname: string,
              private _symbol: string,
              private _isPublic: boolean) {
  }
```

I built a basic json file with some data to retrieve (json-server)
The service layer :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CryptoCurrency} from '../../model/crypto-currency/CryptoCurrency.model';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CryptoCurrencyService {
  baseUrlBackend = 'http://localhost:3000/currencies';

  constructor(private http: HttpClientModule) { }

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get<Array<CryptoCurrency>>(this.baseUrlBackend);
  }
}
```

In my component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CryptoCurrency} from '../../shared/model/crypto-currency/CryptoCurrency.model';
import {CryptoCurrencyService} from '../../shared/services/crypto/CryptoCurrency.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-currencies',
  templateUrl: './currencies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./currencies.component.css'],
  providers: [ CryptoCurrencyService ]
})
export class CurrenciesComponent implements OnInit {
  currency: CryptoCurrency;
  currencies: Array <CryptoCurrency> = [];

  // dependency injection
  constructor(private cryptoCurrencyService: CryptoCurrencyService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cryptoCurrencyService.getAll().subscribe(res => {
      this.currencies = res;
    });
  }
}
```

I declared the HttpClientModule in app.component.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

And in the imports :

```
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
```

Finally in the html file :

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let currency of currencies">
      {{ currency.id }} {{ currency.currencyKeyId}} {{ currency.symbol}} {{ currency.currencyname}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace HttpClientModule in your service with

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and in the constructor:

```
private http: HttpClient
```

If you notice in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http), you only initialize HttpClientModule in the App Component.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be depending on `HttpClientModule` in your *service*, it should only be in your *module* imports. Change `CryptoCurrencyService` to depend on `HttpClient` instead.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```